# How to switch multiple window without using page title in selenium webdriver using java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 windows with same page title and same browser, used different session.
After executing the automation script from first window it opens next window and execute the code. 
I am not able to switch back to the window.

I am using the below code :

```
Set<String> windowIterator = Driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator Iter = windowIterator.iterator();
String Parent = (String) Iter.next();
String sub = (String) Iter.next();
Driver.switchTo().window(sub);`
```

I have tried with the updated script, here also facing issues to switch window.

package ABC;

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;




public class UserChat {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        WebDriver user_1 = new FirefoxDriver();

        user_1.manage().window().maximize();
        user_1.get("url");

        // login user_1
        user_1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("email1");
        user_1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("pass");
        user_1.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);


        WebDriver user_2 = new FirefoxDriver();
        user_2.manage().window().maximize();
        user_2.get("url");

        // login user_2 
        user_2.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='email']")).sendKeys("email2");
        user_2.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='pass']")).sendKeys("pass");
        user_2.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@id='loginbutton']/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);



        //click on Chat     
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(user_2, 60);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/a")));
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        //Search friend to message e.g. for user_1
        user_2.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/input")).sendKeys("My Friend User1");

        //Send message to friend
         WebElement webElement = user_2.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/input"));
         webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
         Thread.sleep(3000);

         WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(user_2, 60);
        WebElement element2 = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[4]/div[1]/textarea")));
        element2.click();

         user_2.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[4]/div[1]/textarea")).sendKeys("hi");
         element2.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
         Thread.sleep(2000);

    //   Actions action = new Actions(user_2);
      //   action.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "T")).build().perform();
      //   action.sendKeys(Keys.ALT,Keys.TAB).build().perform();


         Set<String> handles = user_2.getWindowHandles();
         int index = 0;
        if (handles.size() > index) {
             String handle = handles.toArray()[index].toString();
             user_2.switchTo().window(handle);
        }




    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After done operation on second page use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

For you code you can use something like this :-

```
//Click your link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click();
//Get all the window handles in a set
Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
//iterate through your windows
while (it.hasNext()){
String parent = it.next();
String newwin = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newwin);
//perform actions on new window
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

Comment: I have tried with this script still it is not able to switch window.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two `FirefoxDriver` instances - in effect two different processes. Using web driver you can switch between the windows of a single driver instance. Once you maximise the second driver window, for switching back to the previous driver window - either you have to close the second window (which makes the OS to chose the earlier window to be on top), or minimise the second window or use OS specific library like [Java Native Access](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) to switch between them.

Comment: For minimize window used : ' Dimension windowMinSize = new Dimension(100,100);
   user_2.manage().window().setSize(windowMinSize);' But still not able to switch to that window. Canyou provide me some code for that.

Comment: I have used this script too : ' user_2.manage().window().setPosition(new Point(-2000, 0));'  This is switching to the previous window but latest window is getting hide. Is there any other way or correct my script.

Comment: If it's possible try using native events. Else JNA might be your last option.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different driver instances.

If you want to interact with the first instance again just use the user_1 object.  It's going to be sitting there until you close it.